# Getting a table value from DB with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get exercise id to complete the table, how can I get the exercise ID, like I am getting it in `Auth::user()->id`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\MyExercises;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Exercise;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; 

class MyExerciseController extends Controller
        {

    public function index()
    {
        
        $myexercises = MyExercises::paginate();

        return view('exercises.myexercises', compact('myexercises'));
    }

    public function assign(Request $request)
    {
        $myexercises = MyExercises::create([
            'description' =>$request->description,
            'done' =>$request->done,
            'user_id'  => Auth::user()->id,
            'exercises_id' =>(xxxxxx),
            'place'  =>$request->place,
            'duration'  =>$request->duration,
        ]);
            return redirect()->route('myexercises.index');
```

I have tried doing it like this in the Controller, but right now I am a bit lost on how to proceed, thank you!

```
    public function id()
    {
        $client = DB::table('My_exercises')
            ->where('id', '=', $request->get('id'))
            ->first();
    }
```

Comment: Is the `exercises_id` not in the request, like from a form? ... you can do a `dd($request);` before the `::create` call to see what all the `$request` contains.

Comment: Thank you @PaulT. I have checked it, and it is passing all the previous values, but the exercises_id, have any Idea how can I also pass the exercise_ID?

Comment: From where? ... how is it getting to the `assign` function? ... not knowing the handling, where is `exercises_id` loaded, in the `Auth`, or is it in some other related table?

Comment: `exercises_id` is stored in `Exercises` Table, right now it isn't getting to the `assign` function, thats what I wanted it to do!

Comment: ...is the `Exercises` table a different table than the `My_exercises` table, in the `id()` function?

Comment: Yes, but if I change the tables in the second code snipped it still doesn't work :(

Comment: I suppose you are submitting some sort of `<form>` and you want to pass the ID value along with the other values. Are you familiar with `<input type="hidden"`?  With this you can pass the ID without having it visible on the page. If not, could you provide some more info on whatever is happening before the application gets to the `assign` function?